# How to animate AutoLayout with view sizes proportional

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode7

I have a view which has constraint of proportional height and width with respect to its superview. Now I need to set its height to zero, But I cannot change multiplier to 0 it is read only property.
is There any method to set height zero except i manually set constraint constant value equal to its (-width)?

Comment: you can not change multiplier ... better to inactive that constraint and add programmatically other one as per your use